# Unable to define a class that is declared publicly in another class (and more problems)

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates

I am making a program in which one two classes are very intimately related, and so I would like to declare one of them inside of the other one so the user has to use the Class::member syntax to create and derive from this class type. I have abstracted my program to just 4 classes and recreated the errors. The classes are :

```
GraphInterface, Graph, GraphIteratorInterface, and GraphIterator.
```

Where Graph derives publically from it's interface and likewise with the iterators. Now because the iterators can only be used with these graphs, I want the user to have to create one by going

```
Graph<int>::GraphIterator<int> it;
```

I'm trying to accomplish this by declaring the GraphIteratorInterface class inside of GraphInterface class, then defining it a separate .h file. I then declare GraphIterator inside of the Graph class (which derives from GraphInterface), then define it in it's own cpp file as normal.

Code is here on ideone : http://ideone.com/3fByCl 
When I try and run everything I get the error

```
"error: too few template-parameter-lists class GraphInterface<V>::GraphIteratorInterface {"
```

among other errors. I don't understand how it would be missing template parameters, I definitely gave it one (V).

edit - code is here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class V>
class GraphInterface {
    public:
    // Abstract GraphIterator class, defined elsewhere
    template<class VE> class GraphIteratorInterface;

    virtual ~GraphInterface();

    // BFS that uses the graph iterator class to perform work on the discovered
    // vertices and edges
    virtual void BFS(V src_vertex, GraphIteratorInterface<V> *) = 0;

};

template<class V>
class Graph : public GraphInterface<V> {
    public :
    template<class VE> class GraphIterator; // implements the graph-iter interface

    ~Graph();

    void BFS(V src_vertex, GraphIterator<V> *);
};

template<class V>
class GraphInterface<V>::GraphIteratorInterface {

    virtual void examine_edge(/*Edge Object*/) = 0;
    virtual void discover_vertex(const V &) = 0;
    // ...
};

template<class V>
class Graph<V>::GraphIterator : public GraphInterface<V>::GraphIteratorInterface {
    std::vector<V> vertices;
    //.. other members not in the interface
    void examine_edge(/*Edge Object*/);
    void discover_vertex(const V &)
};

int main() {
    Graph<int> g;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code should be embedded in the question rather than linked.

Comment: I'll change it right now, thanks for pointing it out. I thought the fact that you guys could compile it and see the errors for yourself would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you probably don't need `GraphIteratorInterface` and `GraphIterator` to be templates at all. That is, start with

```
template<class V>
class GraphInterface {
public:
    class GraphIteratorInterface;
```

and continue from here.

The following addresses only the language aspect of member templates. You need not use any of this in your real code.

1. If you *define* a member template of a class template, the syntax is like this:

   ```
   template<class V> 
   template<class VE>
   class GraphInterface<V>::GraphIteratorInterface { ...
   ```

Yes use `template<class XYZ>` twice in a row.

2. When you *use* a member template of a class template, you have to use this syntax:

   ```
   template<class V> 
   template <class VE>
   class Graph<V>::GraphIterator 
     : public GraphInterface<V>::template GraphIteratorInterface<VE> {
   ```

That is, use `::template` intead of `::` before a member template name.

Code with these fixes is [here](http://ideone.com/ptHgyC). It still doesn't compile because of a different problem unrelated to templates.

In essence you have

```
interface XI
 member interface YI
 virtual f(YI)

class XC : XI
 class YC : XI::YI
 virtual f(YC)
```

You cannot override a virtual function like that. A different parameter list means it's a different function. The parameters are closely related but it doesn't matter. YI and YC are two different types.

You have to redesign your interface such that doesn't happen. XC::f must use the same signature as XI::f.

You may want to make YI a template parameter, rather than a member, of XI. That is:

```
template<class V, class Iter>
class GraphInterface {
  public:
    virtual void BSF(V, Iter*) = 0;

  template <class V> 
  class IterImpl { ...

  template <class V>
  class GraphImpl : public GraphInterface <V, IterImpl> { ...
```

You cannot define IterImpl inside GraphImpl this way though.

Comment: Thank you for your help! These template things are a little hard to wrap my head around syntactically. It makes sense that two different signatures would result in two separate functions, but I figured that since Iterator *is a* IteratorInterface, substituting one for the other in the argument list would be valid.

Comment: No worry, this is a very frequent mistake that even seasoned professionals make.